# PHP Apostrophe/single quote pattern matching

Tags: php, parsing

Having a problem with single quote/apostophes in some php I am writing to parse smilies.

The single quote is the bane of my life, but here goes.

First here's some of the code...

First my array which holds the smiley and the filename of that smiley.

This is a separate file (smiley-map.php).

```
<?php 
$smilies = array (
array('code' => ':)', 'filename' => 'smiley.gif'),
array('code' => ':(', 'filename' => 'sad.gif'),
array('code' => ';)', 'filename' => 'wink.gif'),
array('code' => ':D', 'filename' => 'grin.gif'),
array('code' => ';D', 'filename' => 'cheesy.gif'),
array('code' => '>:-(', 'filename' => 'angry.gif'),
array('code' => ':O', 'filename' => 'shocked.gif'),
array('code' => '8)', 'filename' => 'cool.gif'),
array('code' => '???', 'filename' => 'huh.gif'),
array('code' => '::-)', 'filename' => 'rolleyes.gif'),
array('code' => ':P', 'filename' => 'tongue.gif'),
array('code' => ':-[', 'filename' => 'embarrassed.gif'),
array('code' => ':*', 'filename' => 'lipsrsealed.gif'),
array('code' => ':-/', 'filename' => 'undecided.gif'),
array('code' => ':x', 'filename' => 'kiss.gif'),
array('code' => ':\'(', 'filename' => 'cry.gif'),
array('code' => '>:-D', 'filename' => 'evil.gif'),
array('code' => '^-^', 'filename' => 'azn.gif'),
array('code' => 'O0', 'filename' => 'afro.gif'),
array('code' => 'LOL', 'filename' => '2funny.gif'),
array('code' => ':bash:', 'filename' => 'knuppel2.gif'),
array('code' => '>_<', 'filename' => 'tickedoff.gif'),
array('code' => ':?', 'filename' => 'idiot.gif'),
array('code' => ':!', 'filename' => 'uglystupid.gif'),
);
?>
```

Then I parse them in a simple manner like this :

```
 <?php
 function parseSmilies($string)
 {
require_once("smilies/smiley-map.php");

for ($i = 0; $i < count($smilies); $i++)
{
    $filename = '<img src="smilies/' . $smilies[$i]['filename'] . '" alt="smiley" title="' . $smilies[$i]['code'] . '" />';
    $string = str_replace($smilies[$i]['code'], $filename, $string);
}
return $string;
 }
 ?>
```

So it goes...include smile map...array now available...search string for codes...swap code for image tag.

This all works fine on my local machine (XAMPP).  But when I upload and run it in myserver, it misses the cry one :'(

I imagine this is the single quote causing a probelm, despite my having escaped it in the array..

Presumably there is some PHP setting that is affecting this ?

Could anyone advise please ?

Many thanks.

**EDIT: $string originates from $_POST**

Comment: Is the `'` escaped in `$string`? My guess is that it isn't on your development machine, but it is on your server (possibly due to addslashes or similar).

Comment: Sounds like gpc_magic_quotes -- where is `$string` originating from?  By the way You could use a `foreach` there instead of a `for`.  Would save you some typing..

Comment: `require_once`  is the wrong function here, what you mean is `require` .

Comment: @hakre: Never mind my previous question "why is it wrong?", I see you answered that in your answer.

Comment: @Explosion Pills - yeah I think you are right - I had forgot my host has it turned on...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This probably has something to do with [Magic Quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php).
When *Magic Quotes* are turned on in your PHP server, the `'` in all superglobals (`$_GET`, `$_POST` etc.) gets replaced with `\'` and `"` gets replaced with `\"`. This mechanism has been deprecated as of PHP 5.3.0 and removed as of PHP 5.4.0.

However, most web-hosting servers do not even have PHP 5.3.0 yet, while private servers like XAMPP are likely to have a more recent version of PHP. So your localhost probably will not have *Magic Quotes* turned on while your webserver will.

*Magic Quotes* makes it impossible to perform SQL injection when including a superglobal value directly into the query. For example:

```
<?php

$query = 'SELECT id FROM users WHERE name = "' . $_POST['name'] . '" AND password = "' . $_POST['password'] . "'";

?>
```

Someone entering a `1" OR "1" = "1` in the `password` field could easily change the query into `SELECT id FROM users WHERE name = "admin" AND password = "1" OR "1" = "1"` effectively logging in on the administrator account without knowing the password.

---

That said, I think *Magic Quotes* was only a fallback mechanism for people not securing their input and you should always turn it off. It's a better practice to secure your own application instead of letting PHP do it.

### Disabling Magic Quotes

This can be done using `php.ini` but I suppose you don't have access to that file on a hosted server. The following snippet emulates disabling *Magic Quotes*:

```
<?php

if( get_magic_quotes_gcp( ) )
{
    function stripslashes_deep( $val )
    {
        return is_array( $val ) ? array_map( 'stripslashes_deep', $val )
                                : stripslashes( $val );
    }
    
    $_GET     = stripslashes_deep( $_GET );
    $_POST    = stripslashes_deep( $_POST );
    $_COOKIE  = stripslashes_deep( $_COOKIE );
    $_REQUEST = stripslashes_deep( $_REQUEST );
}

?>
```

Comment: Even though `magic_quotes_gpc` might affect the string that is passed I would be a little bit more careful suggesting to disable it.

Comment: @hakre If his smileyparser looks for `:'(` but it can only find `:\'(`, magic quotes actually does cause the problem so disabling it will solve the problem. Turning off magic quotes is also a good practice because it manages consistency between his testing environment and his actual website. You can also argue for enabling magic quotes on his testing server, but as magic quotes is removed in PHP 5.4.0 I think it is better to always turn it off and get used to securing your input by yourself.

Comment: For example it's much more safe, to add slashes to the smiley search sequences in case this is required.

Comment: I think you are on to it, I will investigate thanks.  Magic quotes is off on my local machine, I'm betting it is turned on on my host.

Comment: @hakre The problem is, as servers are slowly updating their PHP versions, one day his server will have *magic quotes* disabled as well. It is - in my opinion - simply a good practice to manage your own security and be prepared for the future.

Comment: Yes, I can understand that argument, I just wanted to remind to play safe for current, not for some problem in the future that might or might not happen. Naturally a well written application should not rely on a defective-by-design feature like magic quotes gpc. If the host is configured wrongly, it's time to talk with the hoser. Changing it's own software that was correctly written, is the wrong way.

Comment: Guy's thanks for your help - I got it working.  My host has magic quotes turned on.  So I test for magic quote and stripslashes($string) and of course the pattern then matches.  And yes re security I will be making sure no SQL can get in there.  I'm not at that stage yet, but I thank your for you advice and concern :)

Comment: @hakre I agree with you on that, but since turning `magic_quotes_gcp` off per site is often not an option provided by the host, I provide a way to simulate a consistent environment. It is a hack indeed, but it actually allows the existing code to run in its current (correct) state instead of having to take into account the possibility that a `:'(` may as well be a `:\'(`. But I think we both get the point :)  
@Rog I'm glad it's working now :)

Answer (score 0):

> I imagine this is the single quote causing a probelm, despite my having escaped it in the array..

No, it does not. That's just not the case.

> Presumably there is some PHP setting that is affecting this ?

No, there is no PHP setting that is affecting that.

> Could anyone advise please ?

You should start writing unit-tests and test your code before letting it go live. For example, you would have found out that your function only works once. Next time it's called, the replacement pairs are just not defined any longer (`require_once` triggers that).

Next to that issue, I can imagine that the data on your live system is different from your local system. If you execute the function on the same data on your local system, you should see that it does not work as well.

Hints:

1. What does `var_dump($string)` give?
2. [`strtr`](http://php.net/strtr).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response.  I know what you are saying re require.  I only need my function to work once so that's not an issue, that;s why I did it that way.  I will take a look at strtr and see if that is a better method. thx :)

Comment: If the function is only called once, don't use `require_once`, that is especially the **wrong** reason to use it. So don't lightly joke about it, this bytes your ass when you start with actually using your software. More importantly, you should `var_dump` the input and add it to your question.

Comment: Btw, I have not gone live yet - I am not that daft ;)  I am just testing modules one at a time to see if they work.

Comment: I don't believe I was making a joke... what do you suggest to use then instead of require_once ?

Comment: Just use `require`, it does exactly what you're looking for with no side-effects.

Comment: @hakre "Bytes" your ass?  How could he use `strtr` here?  I thought that only worked per-character.